# generate a blank response object for testing

Tags: python, flask, response

Is there a way to generate a blank response object with all the attributes, or do I have to create the class myself?

I just want something for a flask app that is cleaner than doing something like this:

```
    class fake_request():
        status_code = None
        text = None
    response = fake_request()
```

Comment: `return "",0`? maybe? otherwise I dont understand what your asking ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but what's wrong with

```
from flask import Response

response = Response()
```

?

[Flask documentation - Response object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#response-objects)

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to generating an instance of an object inline, you can use this syntax

```
response = type('obj', (object,), {'status_code' : None, 'text' : None})
```

**Update** User added *flask* reference after this answer, leaving for reference

Comment: indeed, found this while looking for "generate a blank response object for testing" in python requests context

Comment: This is also useful for anyone needing to convert a `scrapy.Response` object to `requests.Response` object for use in custom middleware that utilize external packages, which in turn (being at the mercy of external dependencies) utilize the `requests` package.

Answer (score 1):

What about subclassing a class you want to fake?

```
import flask
class FakeResponse(flask.Response):
    def __init__(self, response=None, status=None, headers=None, mimetype=None, content_type=None, direct_passthrough=False):
        self.headers = {}
        self.status_code = 200
        self.text = ""
```

As an advantage, FakeResponse interface would strictly conform original Response object (it'll include all properties and methods of original one).